# Close FileDialog programmatically

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm working on a system that connects an `Excel spreadsheet` to an Access back end. Due to symbolic link issues in the network, queries in the spreadsheet linked directly to the Access back end fail if users don't go into Explorer first and connect to drives by clicking on them.

I've found initiating an instance of the folder open dialog, set to the address of the back end database helps to establish the required connection, but leaves the folder browser window open, which the user then has to close, and which also halts all other processes after it.

How do you close the folder browser with `VBA`? I've searched for a few days now, and found `zilch`.

**Edit**: code from comment.

```
Dim NConnect as FileDialog 
Dim NPath as String 

Set NConnect = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 
If Len(Dir(NPath)) = 0 Then 
    With NConnect 
        .InitialFileName = NPath 
        .AllowMultiSelect = False 
        .Show 
    End With 
    DoEvents 

    Application.Wait (Now + Timevalue("00:00:10")) 
    SendKeys "{ESC}", True 
End If
```

Comment: Please post the code you have now.

Comment: A small AutoIt script (compiled to EXE) may be the simplest solution. https://www.autoitscript.com/site/

Comment: Thanks @Andre451, but I'd prefer to have the solution contained within VBA if at all possible.

Comment: Sorry about taking so long to post the code, but here it is.....nothing too complicated really. I've tried emulating hitting ESC, as you can see: 
 
`Dim NConnect as FileDialog  
Dim NPath as String  
Set NConnect = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)  
If Len(Dir(NPath)) = 0 Then  
With NConnect  
.InitialFileName = NPath  
.AllowMultiSelect = False  
.Show  
End With  
DoEvents  
Application.Wait (Now + Timevalue("00:00:10"))  
SendKeys "{ESC}", True  
End If`

Comment: Please **edit** your question and add the code there, so it's readable.

Comment: For some reason, the back ticks and double spaces aren't working for me. I've tried several times to try and edit it. But it is very simple code, nothing at all complicated.

All I need to know is how to close the open folder dialog box once the connection to the database folder has been reestablished.

Comment: The point of posting the code was so that we can play around with it. A block of code is indented by **four** spaces.

Answer (score 0):

So - having played around with it...

In similar cases, what you usually have to do is to schedule the second function **before** executing the first function. Using the [`OnTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx) method, it would look like this:

```
Public Sub OpenFileDialog()

    Dim NConnect As FileDialog
    Const NPath = "X:\your\path"

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "SendEscape"

    Set NConnect = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With NConnect
        .InitialFileName = NPath
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub SendEscape()

    Debug.Print "SendEscape"
    SendKeys "{ESC}", True

End Sub
```

But alas, this doesn't work, [because](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865217.aspx):

> When you call the Show method, no more code executes until the user dismisses the file dialog box.

So it's simply *not possible* to do this with a pure VBA solution - after you open the FileDialog, *nothing* gets executed until it is closed.
The Immediate Window shows when `SendEscape` runs.

But you can delegate the `SendKeys` to a simple VBScript:

```
' save as C:\SendEscape.vbs
WScript.Sleep 5000
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{ESCAPE}"
```

and (again) call this script **before** the FileDialog is opened:

```
Dim NConnect As FileDialog
Const NPath = "X:\your\path"

Shell "wscript C:\SendEscape.vbs"

Set NConnect = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With NConnect
    .InitialFileName = NPath
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
End With
```

This works now, because both threads (Excel and WScript) run in parallel.

Be aware though, that `SendKeys` is a notoriously unreliable method of "remote controlling" things. If the user clicks anywhere else while the FileDialog is open, the ESC gets sent there.
In a production environment I would use AutoIt.

Comment: Thanks @Andre451, for the edit and the answer! Maybe the vb script is the only way to go. I shall give it a shot!

Comment: I think I might have found a solution. Just omit the `.Show` bit. No dialog, no problems!

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a day of testing, it seems as if leaving `.Show` out of OpenDialog establishes a connection with the database, and does not interrupt any other procedures.

I hope this helps anyone else looking for a solution to this problem.